# QMediaplayer: No sound

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmediaplayer

**Problem:**
The following calls don't make QMediaPlayer play any sound.

```
player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/snd/coin-refund.mp3"));
player->play();
```

Where `player` is of type `QMediaPlayer*`.
Where the URL was generated using the QtCreator Copy URL option. So the file for sure is in the .qrc file.

**Details:**

I have a class derived from `QObject` like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // some stuff
    private:
    QMediaPlayer* player;
 }
```

A call to the QMediaPlayer standard constructor in the MyClass constructor like this...

```
MyClass::MyClass() :
    player(new QMediaPlayer)
{
}
```

... causes the following error message on runtime (application compiles without any warnings)

> QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with
>   QThread

Removing the player removes this message (I haven't explicitly created any QThreads or QTimers).

In my .pro file I have :

```
QT += core gui webkitwidgets multimedia multimediawidgets widgets
```

**Additional Information:**
 I'm on Arch Linux, using QtCreator 4.2.2 and Qt 5.8.0

**EDIT:**

[github link](https://github.com/tangboshi/julia_c/tree/master/qt/haasesautomat)

[ldd output (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/f34V5hAH)

Comment: Have you installed the codecs for mp3? I am using Archlinux, Qt 5.8 and I have no problems ... you could help better if you can share your project via github, dropbox or similar.

Comment: You could run: `ldd your_executable` and show what you get.

Comment: @eyllanesc added github link as requested.

Comment: @eyllanesc added ldd output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the object does not start properly in the constructor, the solution I have found so far to create the object every time you want to do `play()`.

```
void automaton::vendorSlot(const unsigned int buttonPressed)
{
    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    switch (buttonPressed)
    [...]
```

Comment: This worked for me, too! Strange that it doesnt work when initialized in the class constructor...